# A comparison between 'in' and 'of'

Tags: prepositions, in-of

Which one of the following self-made sentences sounds more correct to you:

> - His father holds the foremost position in the tribe.
> - His father holds the foremost position of the tribe.

Comment: "position of the tribe" could also mean some policy or rule, for example: "It is the foremost position of the tribe that all children should be properly educated." Normally, as an individual in a group, use "in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, although using **in** sounds more natural, as it can be inferred that the father is in the tribe.